# Rest API to get Android apps Statistics from Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, developer-console

I'm looking for a Rest API to retrive all the statistics of all my apps in the Google Play Developer console and use them to generate a dashboard.

I'm looking for a way of get "Installed Audience", "User Acquisitions", etc
Exaclty what Google Play Developer Console gives me on statistics page.

I was searching but I can't found an API for this. There is APIs for crashs, to upload Apks, but not to get statistics.

Someone know if this API exist?

Comment: Hello! Seems at all has not public API.  I have look on front-end api, it is gRPC gateway to REST.I have to extract some API from website, and have way to login, please contact me.